# c# wp7 checkable list

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, checkbox

What's the simplest way to create a list that has the option to be check-able, just like the linked inbox in windows phone (image attached) ? I  want the list to be initially without checkboxes, then with a button click a checkbox appears next to each item just like the inbox.

Any ideas will be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) `MultiselectList`

Sample screenshot:

[image]